# Stack Overflow/ Stack Exchange post formatting

Tags: support

Looking at the help information, it suggests that I can use markdown and/or html to help with formatting Stack Exchange community questions/answers.

What I'm finding in case of stackoverflow.com community questions/answers input boxes is that markdown two spaces on end of line and html `<br/>` do not produce a new line and hitting enter has the effect of submitting the question/answer.

In this meta.stackoverflow.com community hitting enter does produce a new line versus submitting the question.

Any pointers to what I'm overlooking?

Comment: Hitting enter shouldn't be submitting the question.  That's odd.  (Though it *will* submit a comment since comments are 1-line)

Comment: As @Pokechu22 hinted, you seem to be describing the behaviour for comments, not questions and answers. You should be able to use either double-space-and-end-of-line or `<br />` to insert a break between two lines. If this doesn't work, can you provide an example in your post?

Answer (score 1):

For line break, you can either use html `<br>` or two spaces at the end of current line followed by a newline (enter).

Please note that it's `<br>`, not `<br/>`.

You will find all the formatting information here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `<br/>`, `<br />` and `<br />` all work fine in Stack Overflow's parser and the HTML5 parsing specification.